# Firebase security rules to an specific field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm starting to use Cloud Firestore and I have a question about the security rules. I need to know if I can set write permissions to a specific field. For example I have a collection named "tickets" and each document is:

```
ticket\
    id: "firebaseIdklnalskdla",
    status: "in_progress"
    creation_date: "28/08/2018"
```

I need to specify "write" permissions only to the "status" field. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase team come up with a very interesting explanatory video where they talk about this case: https://youtu.be/8Mzb9zmnbJs?t=1313
After document creation you can setup restrictions on which fields can actually be altered.

Answer (score 0):

the security rules might look about like this (not tested):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

  // here one can limit per user and other conditions, not per field. 
  match /tickets/{ticket} {
      allow update: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
  }

}
```

[Structuring Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) explains it and

meanwhile there also is a [Firestore Security Rules Simulator](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/06/announcing-firestore-security-rules.html).

Comment: The question is about Firestore, but you're showing Realtime Database rules.  They're very different.

Comment: @DougStevenson changed that.

Comment: Did you try this to see if it works?  I suspect it won't, because Firestore doesn't allow per-field security rules.

Comment: @DougStevenson realized that while trying to convert the rules - telling apart by user groups is better than nothing... one could maybe check for `request.data['status']`; in general, Firebase might be more suitable for the demand, because it permits more granular rules (the one does not exclude the other)... the title of the question still reads "Firebase".